# how static library link

Tags: c++, linux, static

In lib.a def:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "fun_a.h"

void fun_a() {
    return;
}

void fun_nocall_a(){
    return;
}
```

`g++ main.cpp -L./ -la`

to my understanding，a.out should not link fun_nocall_a, but nm output:

```
00000000006008e0 d _DYNAMIC 0000000000600aa8 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_ 0000000000400738 R _IO_stdin_used
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
                 w _Jv_RegisterClasses 000000000040061b T _Z12fun_nocall_av 0000000000400635 T _Z12fun_nocall_bv 00000000004005f8 T _Z15fun_nocall_mainv
```

It has link fun_nocall_a;

**another test:**

```
#include "fun_a.h"
#include "hiredis.h"

void fun_nocall_main() {
    return;
}

int main() {
    redisConnect(NULL,0);
    fun_a();
    return 0;
}
```

Use Redis lib, I find that some function linked by a.out, but some not;

```
0000000000402e70 T redisAppendCommand
0000000000401b80 T redisAppendCommandArgv
00000000004017e0 T redisAppendFormattedCommand
0000000000401de0 T redisBufferRead
0000000000402240 T redisBufferWrite
0000000000406fa0 T redisCheckSocketError
0000000000404050 T redisCommand
0000000000403fd0 T redisCommandArgv
0000000000402050 T redisConnect
00000000004021b0 T redisConnectBindNonBlock
0000000000401ee0 T redisConnectFd
0000000000401390 T redisConnectNonBlock
0000000000402140 T redisConnectUnix
```

my question is :

> what's principle when link static library？

Comment: Are you defining `fun_a` in the main ? It should be declared in fun_a.h, defined in fun_a.cpp then compiled into a static lib. And when you want to use fun_a into another project (executable, lib), you just call it. And link the lib when compiling.

Comment: In main, not defining fun_a,  fun_a just define in fun_a.cpp. I want to know why execute files link function which not used.